# MagicalRecord get all entities from one to many relationship where relationship id is x

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Say I have an entity called Message, and an entity called Group. Every group can have many messages (one to many relationship).
How do I use MagicalRecord to get all the messages of a group, WITHOUT first loading the group?

NSArray *entities = [Message MR_findAllSortedBy:@"groupID:x" ascending:NO];

I thought of just adding an attribute groupID to message, but it seems very wrong... (since obviously the relationship is saved in my db in some other way)

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like:

```
NSArray *messagesInGroup = [Message MR_findAllSortedBy:@"group.groupID" ascending:NO]
```

The sortedBy parameter just translates into the `[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:ascending:]` method. According to the documentation, that first parameter is a keyPath, so as long as it's valid (ie. exists), it will work for you.